# Adding 'at least one day off' constraint

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I simplified an example of what I am trying to do below. I have a weekly schedule and a few different 'slots' to fill, where I am maximizing around a given value per person assigned to each slot.

I am trying to add a constraint that says they each get one day off. I have seen similar questions but I am having trouble translating them to this so any help is appreciated.

My thought was that I could take the max for each person per day which would be 1 on any days they are currently assigned, then sum those for all of the days and try to get that to be less than or equal to 2 (of the 3 days).

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

assignments = {}

people = ['Max','Josh']

days = {
    'Monday':['7','8','9','10'],
    'Tuesday':['6','7','8','9','10'],
    'Wednesday':['7','8','9','10']
}

default_thing_we_like = 50

thing_we_like_per_employee_per_slot = {
    ('Max','Monday','7'): 100,
    ('Max','Tuesday','7'): 150,
    ('Max','Wednesday','7'): 200,
}

# make vars
for person in people:
    for day in days:
        for hour in days[day]:
            assignments[(person,day,hour)] = model.NewBoolVar(f'{person}-{day}-{hour}')

# fill each spot
for day in days:
    for hour in days[day]:
        model.Add(sum(assignments[(person,day,hour)] for person in people) == 1)

# everyone should get at least one of these days off
for person in people:
    for day in days:
        model.Add(sum(max(assignments.get((person,day,hour),0) for hour in days[day]) for day in days) <= 2)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

model.Maximize(sum(thing_we_like_per_employee_per_slot.get((person, day, hour),default_thing_we_like) * assignments[(person,day,hour)]
                                                    for hour in days[day]
                                                    for day in days
                                                    for person in people
                                                    ))


solution_printer = cp_model.ObjectiveSolutionPrinter()
status = solver.SolveWithSolutionCallback(model, solution_printer)

if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    ret_slots = []
    for person in people:
        print(f"{person} is working: ")
        for day in days:
            for hour in days[day]:
                if (solver.Value(assignments[(person,day,hour)])):
                    print(f"{day} at {hour} with",thing_we_like_per_employee_per_slot.get((person, day, hour),default_thing_we_like),"things we like.")
else:
    print("uh oh")
```

The result I get running this is:

```
Solution 0, time = 0.00 s, objective = 900
Max is working: 
Monday at 7 with 100 things we like.
Monday at 9 with 50 things we like.
Tuesday at 6 with 50 things we like.
Tuesday at 7 with 150 things we like.
Tuesday at 8 with 50 things we like.
Tuesday at 9 with 50 things we like.
Tuesday at 10 with 50 things we like.
Wednesday at 7 with 200 things we like.
Wednesday at 8 with 50 things we like.
Wednesday at 9 with 50 things we like.
Wednesday at 10 with 50 things we like.
Josh is working: 
Monday at 8 with 50 things we like.
Monday at 10 with 50 things we like.
```

It assigns Max to all 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `max, min, or, and` with variables created by ortools.

To model these kind of constraints it is easier to just create intermediate variables.

```py
works_day = {
    (person, day): model.NewBoolVar(f"{person}-{day}")
    for person in people
    for day in days
}
```

```py
for person in people:
    for day in days:
        for hour in days[day]:
            assignments[(person, day, hour)] = model.NewBoolVar(
                f"{person}-{day}-{hour}"
            )
            model.AddImplication(
                assignments[(person, day, hour)], works_day[person, day]
            )
```

```
for person in people:
    model.Add(sum(works_day[person, day] for day in days) <= 2)
```

Comment: This is perfect and helps with a number of other similar things I need to do! I hadn't considered using AddImplication like that, very cool.

Comment: Yep, just don't forget that this is just an implication, depending of what you want to do you may also have to write

`model.Add(sum(assignments[(person, day, hour)] for hour in days[day]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(woks_day[person, day].Not())`

Comment: The last equation is implied by the AddImplication.  What you need is the reverse: `model.AddBoolOr([assignments[...]).OnlyEnforceIf(works_day)`.